# grofit package for growth curves and prediction?

Tags: r, curve-fitting, growth-model

I am trying to use grofit package for biological growth curves. I would like to see which curves describe best my data and from them predict results I don’t have.

I basically have a sample of data containing wing length of some birds (as a growth measure) and their respective ages. And I have another sample just with wing lengths (not associated with an age). The format is a little different than what is specified on the package. What I would like to do is:

1) Find the best curve that describes my data (using the data that I have ages),

2) Apply the results to the data I don’t have ages, and predict these ages.

Is it possible with grofit? Any ideas how to do it?